# Using rev in scale_x_discrete makes bar width smaller

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was trying to reverse the order of my bar charts in `scale_x_discrete` with this code:  `scale_x_discrete("", limits = rev(mt2$cyl))`

While it reverses the order of the vars it also makes the width of the bars shrink and makes them unequally spaced. I can factor it and not worry about this but, I am curious why adding `rev(mt2$cyl)` alters the width and spacing of the bars?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mt2 <- mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl, gear) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(pct = 100*n/sum(n)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate( gear = as.character(gear),
         cyl = as.character(cyl))

#smaller width 
ggplot(mt2) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=cyl, y=pct, fill=gear),stat = 'identity',width = .9) +
  scale_x_discrete("", limits = rev(mt2$cyl))




#normal width
ggplot(mt2) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=cyl, y=pct, fill=gear),stat = 'identity',width = .9)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You want `rev(unique(mt2$cyl))` instead. Note the blank spaces in the graphs exactly correspond to duplicate values in `cyl`.

Comment: @joran that did that trick! thanks for that